# How to call method whenever screen loaded, Like always should call method in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation, render

I am developing react native project and I am loading some graphs from server response.
It is a Tab based app and this code is written in first tab.

But, In some use cases that data is not loading to that graph properly.

I have written that code in   **componentDidMount()**, But it will call only once. But, My requirement is I have to call whenever view loaded, That time only **render** method is calling.

I have tried to add **addlistener** for **navigation**, But, Due to its it not navigation stack throwing error.

I have found some solution like below.

```
componentDidMount() {

   }

  fetchGraphData = () => {
  //some code fetching from DB and redux based on conditions
  }

  render() {

  this.fetchGraphData();
    return (

 );
  }
}
```

But, This is not good practice as per code standards.

> I am not receiving props, But, We are using some graphs which are
>   loading from data. My requirement is I have to call api fetch data
>   method after screen load every time.

Any suggestions, I have to call that **fetchGraphData()** once render method or view loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by whenever a view is loaded? componentDidMount does fire after the render function.

Comment: Its screen. Updated title

Comment: You can use `componentDidUpdate` if you are getting the props from a reducer

Comment: I am not receiving props, But, We are using some graphs which are loading from data. My requirement is I have to call api fetch data method after screen load every time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you move the '`fetchGraphData`' function to a screen with the '`fetchGraphData`' function, you must execute it. This problem can be solved by something simpler than I thought.

```js
componentDidMount() {
   this.fetchGraphData();
}
```

You can try rendering again when you move to a screen with a function.

```js
this.props.navigation.push('functionMoveScreen') // Rendering the screen again.
```

Comment: We are not doing any navigation.push, I already mentioned in question, We are using Tabbar means stacknavigator. componentDidMount will call only once after app loaded. But, Here I have to call that fetchGraphData whenever screen loads. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Even if you use a tabbar navigator, you can still use the move screen command.

Comment: But, using this can't achieve my requirement.

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. Actually, We have switch case in Main class from there based on tap we are showing each tab, Not by using navigation. That is why we cant able to use navigation here.